# Excel VBA clearcontents wont work if multiple cells are selected and removed

Tags: excel, vba

Basically trying autopopulate cell CD when a cell in column A is filled, but when emptied the value in CD should also be empty. When deleting one by one it works, but for example if you select multiple cells in A ; A14:A16 and delete, the value in CD doesnt get removed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'auto populate cell CD dropshipment naar No als er een cell in kolom A na rij 13 is gevuld met een waarde
   With Target                   'get out if the change ...
      If .Row < 14 Then Exit Sub    'is in any row <= the reserve area at the top of my sheet
      Select Case .Column
         Case Cells(1, "A").Column
            If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
                With .Offset(0, 81)
                    .Value = "No"
                End With
            End If
            If IsEmpty(Target) Then
                With .Offset(0, 81)
                    .ClearContents
                End With
            End If
            Next Value
      End Select
   End With
```

Comment: Side note: `Cells(1, "A").Column` can be simplified to `1`.

Comment: You have the loop `For Each Value In Target`, but you never use `Value` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Populate or Clear Contents

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TGT_FIRST_CELL As String = "A14"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "CD"
    Const DST_STRING As String = "No"
    
    Dim trg As Range:
    With Me.Range(TGT_FIRST_CELL)
        Set trg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim crg As Range, prg As Range, icell As Range, dcell As Range
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        Set dcell = icell.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
        If IsEmpty(icell.Value) Then
            BuildRange crg, dcell
        Else
            BuildRange prg, dcell
        End If
    Next icell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not crg Is Nothing Then crg.ClearContents
        If Not prg Is Nothing Then prg.Value = DST_STRING
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub BuildRange(ByRef builtRange As Range, addedRange As Range)
    If builtRange Is Nothing Then
        Set builtRange = addedRange
    Else
        Set builtRange = Union(builtRange, addedRange)
    End If
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- To make it work for multiple cells (see comment below), use the following instead:

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    PopulateOrClearOnChange "A14", "CD", "No", Target
    PopulateOrClearOnChange "X14", "BD", "NL01", Target
    PopulateOrClearOnChange "AB14", "BE", "BE01", Target
    PopulateOrClearOnChange "AF14", "BF", "NL13", Target
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateOrClearOnChange( _
        TargetFirstCellAddress As String, _
        DestinationColumn As String, _
        DestinationString As String, _
        Target As Range)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim trg As Range:
    With ws.Range(TargetFirstCellAddress)
        Set trg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim prg As Range, crg As Range, icell As Range, dcell As Range
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        Set dcell = icell.EntireRow.Columns(DestinationColumn)
        If IsEmpty(icell.Value) Then
            BuildRange crg, dcell
        Else
            BuildRange prg, dcell
        End If
    Next icell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not crg Is Nothing Then crg.ClearContents
        If Not prg Is Nothing Then prg.Value = DestinationString
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub BuildRange(ByRef builtRange As Range, addedRange As Range)
    If builtRange Is Nothing Then
        Set builtRange = addedRange
    Else
        Set builtRange = Union(builtRange, addedRange)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! How can  I add more cells to this? i.e filling cell X with values has to fill cell BD with NL01, AB to BE has to fill BE01 and AF to BF has to fill NL13 can I simply repeat this?
   
    `Const TGT_FIRST_CELL As String = "X14"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "BD"
    Const DST_STRING As String = "NL01"`

Comment: The multiple variant doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works on my end, see the screenshot showing the results of my test. You may have accidentally turned off events. Turn them back on by running the following sub: `Sub TurnOn: Application.EnableEvents = True: End Sub`.

Comment: That was indeed the issue thanks it works now!

Answer (score 0):

- `Target.Column` equals `Target.Cells(1).Column`. It is not enought to validate the Target location. Use `.Columns.Count = 1 And .Column = 1` to validate if Target is in Col A. The same issue applies to `Target.Row`.
- When changing cells in the `Change` event code, it's crucial to include `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent multiple triggering of the Change event.
- If users select multiple cells, the condition `If IsEmpty(Target) Then` may not work. Consider using a `For Each` loop to iterate through each cell in Target.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133240)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'auto populate cell CD dropshipment naar No als er een cell in kolom A na rij 13 is gevuld met een waarde
    With Target                   'get out if the change ...
        If .Columns.Count = 1 And .Column = 1 Then
            Dim c As Range
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each c In Target.Cells
                If c.Row > 13 Then _
                 c.Offset(0, 81).Value = IIf(IsEmpty(c.Value), "", "No")
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```